# A word to describe the second one in 2 things

Tags: word-request, nouns, numbers

I'm looking for a word to describe the second one in 2 things (in a situation the the first one was mentioned previously)

Comment: Do you mean "the other"?

Answer (score 4):

[**latter**](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=latter%20definition)

adjective

...

2.
denoting the second or second mentioned of two people or things.

"the Russians could advance into either Germany or Austria—they chose the latter option"

synonyms:   last-mentioned, second-mentioned, second of the two, second, last, later

Answer (score 1):

The word you're looking for is "latter." In a sentence, this refers to the second of two items listed. The word for the first item listed is, "former."

Example: 
*I like to have granola or cereal for breakfast. The former is my favorite, but, the latter has more variety*

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Your suggestion may be valid and very useful; it could be made even better with a cited definition or source to back it up. For future reference, it's always a good idea to include some evidence with your answers.